# The present perfect or the past simple with "every day this week"?

Tags: present-perfect

I don't know which ones are correct.

> 1 I woke up at 7 AM every day this week.
>
> 2 I have woken up at 7 AM every day this week.
>
> 3 When did you wake up every day this week?
>
> 4 When have you woken up every day this week?

I hear different opinions from natives. What do you say?

Comment: Do you already know the difference between simple past and present perfect? The exact same difference applies here.

Comment: It's not that easy as you think. There is not only one difference between the two. Sometimes they are interchangeable, sometimes not. I was told by a native that 4 is not good

Comment: Simple past means the week is finished. Like it's Saturday and I'm not going to wake up again this week. Present perfect means it isn't finished yet, like maybe it's Thursday and I'm going to wake up a couple more times this week. All the sentences are grammatically correct, but the two questions are very odd semantically because it's weird to expect someone has woken up at the same time every day this week.

Comment: Wait a second. How come the week is finished? If it was finished it would be LAST WEEK not THIS WEEK.

Comment: Both (3) and (4) would be more natural with _what time_ instead of _when_.

Comment: Did you read the sentence after that? I explain what I mean.

Comment: gotube, but it's not so black and white. Do you think that it would be a mistake to say on Thursday "I got up at different time every day this week"?